# Why is method returning true without break but false with break? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, process

I have a bit of a puzzler here.

Background: I have an application that logs files that have been viewed after a user selects which files to show.

However, I also have a WinForm appear after they have selected the file that remains hidden until they close out of the file they are viewing.

Here is the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ViewTracker
{
    public partial class NewFile : Form
    {
        //checks to see if a file is open       
        public NewFile()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            OpenDocuments();
            //starts the timer component
            tm_CountDown.Start();


            while (CheckFileIsOpen() == false)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
            this.Show();
        }

        //timer to count down
        //executes every 1 second, interval of the timer component
        private void tm_CountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region METHODS AND EVENTS

        //opens documents based on file selection
        private void OpenDocuments()
        {
        }

        //SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING (files at least)
        private void CloseEverything()
        {
        }

        //checks to see if a file is open and when the file closes shows the new file select dialog
        private bool CheckFileIsOpen()
        {
            Process[] pr_excel = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
            Process[] pr_word = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
            Process[] pr_pdf = Process.GetProcessesByName("ACROBAT");
            if (pr_excel.Count() != 0)
            {
                while (pr_excel[0].HasExited == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (pr_word.Count() != 0)
            {
                while (pr_word[0].HasExited == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (pr_pdf.Count() != 0)
            {
                while (pr_pdf[0].HasExited == false) ;
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            else if (prisonImages.Visible == true)
            {
                while (prisonImages.Visible == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue arises at `while (CheckFileIsOpen() == false)`. If I put a break in Visual Studio at the line and then step through, the program runs as expected (the form stays hidden until the processes are gone). However, if I run without the break, it appears as if the process was never running.

I have tried `Thread.Sleep(1000)` before the `while (CheckFileIsOpen() == false)` statement to see if maybe just stopping the thread for a few seconds may give it a chance to let the process open, but then the whole application just freezes indefinitely.

The questions:
Is my application just reacting too fast to catch the processes and firing before they open? And if so, what are some options I can use to try and keep it from jumping straight to assuming no processes are open?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

I ended up finding a solution a few minutes after posting this.
I changed around some of execution steps and ended up using the `Process.WaitForExit()` method to meet my requirements.

In case anyone is wondering, here is how `CheckFileIsOpen()` works now:

```
 private void CheckFileIsOpen()
    {
        Process[] pr_excel = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
        Process[] pr_word = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
        Process[] pr_pdf = Process.GetProcessesByName("ACROBAT");
        if (pr_excel.Count() != 0)
        {
            pr_excel[0].WaitForExit();
        }

        else if (pr_word.Count() != 0)
        {
            pr_word[0].WaitForExit();
        }

        else if (pr_pdf.Count() != 0)
        {
            pr_pdf[0].WaitForExit();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Only one of your `while` loops in `CheckFileIsOpen()` can loop more than once, and that's the one with the sneaky little `;` on the end of the same line.

Comment: Why do you implement this with busy waits (the while-loops)? A better approach is using a timer and check status occasionally.

Comment: Instead of using timers or while loops, just have events in your `Form` object. Subscribe to those events from the owner application, and then respond to those events in their handlers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx (See Event-Driven validation section)

Answer (score 0):

With your while-loop approach you are blocking the gui thead and your application freezes.

Call `this.Hide()` in your constructor and use another timer. In the timer tick event call your method `CheckFileIsOpen()` if this returns false call `this.Show()` and stop the timer.